# Excel VBA MSXML2 Post response body empty runtime error -2147467260

Tags: vba, excel, msxml2

I would like to post data to Jira using this method :

```
Private IEService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Public Function httpPOST(baseUrl As String, url As String, jsonInput As String, auth As String) As String

    Dim accept As String

    accept = "application/json"

    With IEService
    .Open "POST", baseUrl & url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", accept
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & auth
        .setRequestHeader "Origin", baseUrl

        .send jsonInput
        httpPOST = .responseText
        'MsgBox (.responseText)
    End With

End Function
```

Data is fine and the POST is executed on the back end side. But Jira in this instance returns an empty response body. 
When this happens VBA crashes on  **.send jsonInput** with error : runtime error -2147467260

Seems like MSXML2 does not handle empty responses.  But I haven't found anyone facing same issue searching on the web. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how to fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: I have not got much experience with the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` object and its methods. However if your problem is that it's crashing when you send an invalid request, then just add some error handling. If you know what makes the request invalid *before you send it*, then just do `IF` checks to stop such requests being sent out. If you still can't get that to work, then try wrapping in `On Error Resume Next ... .send ... On Error Goto 0`

Comment: the request is valid and so is the reply, it should return empty when it succeeds. Adding the error catch prevents the problem, but there must be a better way. I cant believe this is normal to get this error because of empty response.

Comment: Yes; `On Error` statements should ideally be avoided if the root cause of the error is not well understood. Perhaps if you could post some example function inputs, it would be helpful for others trying to recreate the problem.